# Read the data from @KafkaListener when user hits GET request using Spring boot and spring Kafka

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, spring-kafka

```java
@Service
public class KafkaConsumer {
    
    @KafkaListener(id = "Id", topics = "topic1")
    public void listen(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Key - " + msg);
    }
}

@RestController
public class GetKafkaData {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/api/get")
    public String getKafkaListnerData() {
        // Some code that need to write to get data from kafka Listner
    }
}
```

Explanation of the above classes.

1. KafkaConsumer - Listen to the data from the Kafka
2. GetKafkaData - Controller which gets the listened data from Kafka.

I'm not adding my Producer and Other Controller which is basically publishing data to Kafka.

So my question is once I hit the `localhost:8080/api/get` API it should call the `listen()` method from the `KafkaConsumer` Class and returns the response as the consumed data from the kafka.

In the above case `listen()` method gets called once you published data into Kafka from the producer.

I'm using the following libraries for development.

**1. Spring boot**

**2. Spring Kafka**

Comment: I do not understand your usecase? Your listener polls indefinitely and your code inside listen() gets executed once a message has been published to the topic you listen on. If I understand you correctly you want to display the history? So you either need to persist the data of the single consumer (as you may have more than one) or you remove the autoconfiguration and start a single kafka listener that reads the kafka log from beginning...

Comment: Actually, I want to invoke the `listen()` method once I hit the GET API i.e. `GetKafkaData` Controller. Till data should be in Kafka.

Comment: Then you probably need to work without the @KafkaListener annotation and write your own KafkaConsumer you start once someone hits your GET endpoint. The spring kafka consumer is confiured in a way that it reads data automatically and calls your listen() method AUTOMATICALLY once new data is published to kafka. So if you want the data from your kafka topic your approach will not work. You either need to persist it somehow (which is the purpose of the kafka log) or you create a custom consumer which ready from beginning once GET is called

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you describe that you need is not possible from logical perspective.

```
@KafkaListener(id = "Id", topics = "topic1")
    public void listen(String msg) {
        System.out.println("Key - " + msg);
    }
```

The point of this method is to be called, when kafka triggers the listener because of some published data in `topic1`. Actually the kafka listener does an infinite loop around `poll`, so it is constantly looking for published data, and if there are (found with `poll`), then it tries to read them.

So a background thread runs which constantly does the `poll` and invokes your method `listen` when needed.

As you understand this is an asynchronous process which can't be served per client request on some other method, since the originating logical component is the scheduler which does the background job and then calls your method `listen`.

So to your logical requirements, the `@KafkaListener` is not providing any help.

You could try to create your own `KafkaConsumer` and manually `poll` the kafka cluster when the client makes a get request to your method `getKafkaListnerData`. Check [here](https://documentation.mapp.com/1.0/en/consume-data-through-the-kafka-consumer-api-10526792.html) a very simple example of how you can manually create the consumer.

[Here](https://kafka.apache.org/26/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)  is also the documetation for `KafkaConsumer` where you can see what options are available for you to use for your manual handling. Probably you will need some specific subscription and then you should use a single `poll` to extract the data that you want. Don't forget to close the consumer when you don't need it any more since otherwise it would lead to leak of resources.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Application context interface and use the BindingService to bind/unbind topics from kafka. This methods works with **Kafka-streams**

```
@Component
public class ConsumerService {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    public void start(String channelName) {

        final BindingService bindingService = this.applicationContext.getBean(BindingService.class);

        final Map<String, SubscribableChannel> subscribableChannelMap = this.applicationContext
                .getBeansOfType(SubscribableChannel.class);

        bindingService.unbindConsumers(channelName);
        bindingService.bindConsumer(subscribableChannelMap.get(channelName), channelName);

    }

    public void stop(String channelName)  {

        final BindingService bindingService = this.applicationContext.getBean(BindingService.class);

        bindingService.unbindConsumers(channelName);

    }
}
```